# Java JButton aligning using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, user-interface

I've already search, read and watch many tutorials about GridBagLayouts but I always having an error while I'm dealing with my buttons. How can I get rid of the wide spacing between button 1 and 2?

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    //pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


    Dimension d = new Dimension(300,0);

    pane.setBackground(Color.red);
    pane.setPreferredSize(d);



    JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
    c.gridy=0;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.weightx =1;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

    pane.add(b1, c); 

    JButton b2 = new JButton ("2");
    c.gridy=1;
    c.weighty = 2;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

    pane.add(b2, c);


    getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.WEST);
    setTitle("test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(900,500);
    setVisible(true);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3tbp.png)

sorry I'm a beginner with gui. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you wanted to have as a result. But I have this as result:

[image: JButton aligning]

The biggest problem in the code, you should have to define an instance of GridbagConstraints for each Button. After that you can set the alignments. And here is how I did it:

```
    JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    Dimension d = new Dimension(300,0);
    pane.setBackground(Color.red);
    pane.setPreferredSize(d);

    GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();       
    JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
    c1.gridx = 0;
    c1.gridy = 0;
    c1.weightx = 1.0;   
    c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    pane.add(b1, c1); 

    GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();       
    JButton b2 = new JButton ("2");
    c2.gridx = 0;
    c2.gridy = 1;
    c2.weighty = 1.0;
    c2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    pane.add(b2, c2);
```